# document.getElementsByTagName doesnt word in IE when HTML loaded using Ajax

Tags: jquery, dom

when loading content via ajax requests,
If the response is:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">To Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">To Yahoo</a>
    <a href="http://www.digg.com">To Digg</a>
</div>
```

With the jquery loaded, and after content loading, i call a function that do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hrefs = "";
var texts = "";
$('#container').find('A').each(function(){
    hrefs += ", " + $(this).attr('href');
    texts += ", " + $(this).html();
});
</script>
```

FF and Safari works fine and gain access to the links loaded.
IE sucks so bad; it behaves like they don't exist.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Barry;

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is only one element with the ID `container` present?

Comment: Did you try sticking an `alert(html)` at the end there? I'm guessing your script possibly isn't running at all.

Comment: Please show the full original script.

Comment: Yes, there's only one div with id="container"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How do you ensure you call the method only after the DOM has been loaded? With `$(document).ready`?
2. Try using lowercase (though HTML is case insensitive) and doing `find('a')` or using `children('a')`

Comment: Just call it inside a `<script>` tag in the end of the document to be sure.